# Android Studio Debug two modules at once

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

I am somewhat familiar with the Android Development environment. Using Eclipse, I have the ability to Debug two/multiple projects at once.

I have not figured out how to do this with Android Studio.  I have two modules, a service and activity, that I would like to Debug simultaneously.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: In my experience you can play multiple projects, but you can't debug them  simultaneously

Comment: I currently have two devices connected, 2 android studio 2.2 RC2 instances (2 projects) and both with a debug session. One device is connected with an usb cable, the other through the network via an 'adb connect @IP'. It works smoothly.

Answer (score 12):

You can debug multiple processes at once, with some limitations.

- If you have multiple project windows open at once in the same single installation of Android Studio, you can run and debug applications from each of them.
- If you have multiple modules in one Android Studio project, then you can only debug one of them via the **Debug** command in the **Run** menu (which is the usual way to debug an app). If you try to debug (or even run) a second module while the first is running, it will clobber the first one. ***However***, if you install the second module and get it running without using the **Run** command in Android Studio (i.e. you launch it manually from the device, or in your case, send an intent to start the service), then you can attach to the running process and debug it without losing your debug session in the first module. To do that, use the **Attach debugger to Android process** command in the **Run** menu. When you do this, you will see two tabs in Android Studio's **Debug** window and you can flip back and forth between them.
- I don't believe you can have two different IDEs (i.e. Android Studio and Eclipse/ADT or two different installations of Android Studio) debugging applications at the same time on the same host machine. They both fight for control of the ADB connection, and everybody loses.